# REST API container create and port bindings

Tags: json, rest, docker, lxc

I have image from dockerfile, which setup container, but I need to create and start containers with docker REST API.  Problem is that I have issue with exposing ssh port. 
I have removed  EXPOSE from dockerfile, and build image.

After that I made POST request on /containers/create with this json:

```
{"Image":"frantiseks/apac","ExposedPorts":{"22/tcp":{}},"Memory":600000,"CpuShares":50}
```

Container was successfully created so as next step I started it with this `POST` request  `/containers/$id/start` with JSON:

```
{"PortBindings": { "22/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "11022" }] }}
```

But after inspect container I do not see mapped ports, so container does not exposed 22 to host 11022 port. 
I am using version 0.7.1.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

PS: Inspected container:
http://jsonblob.com/52b01e45e4b0439bc58ec8d4

Comment: No I did not, I found workaround to use only docker internal LAN, and not to exposed any ports.

Comment: Can you please upgrade to latest version and see if problem resolves?

Answer (score 1):

(Apologies for the late answer, "community" decided to bump your question)

With the [current 1.24 api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/create-a-container), this is all done in the container create. You need to include the following there:

```
   "HostConfig": {
     "PortBindings": { "22/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "11022" }] },
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
`{HostIp:"", HostPort:"11022"}` ?